# Focus control inside DataGridView control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, focus

I have a Form, that contain a DataGridView control named gridParameters.
I'm adding control on-top of it, based on some values, to add controls that are not available (for example, DateTimePicker):

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
gridParameters.Controls.Add(dtp);
dtp.Location = rowCellLocation;
dtp.Size = rowCellSize;
dtp.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtp.Tag = rowId;
dtp.ValueChanged += dtp_SelectedValueChanged;
dtp.Visible = true;
```

That code is inside a loop that iterate throgh the grid rows, and is in an If statement (I add DateTimePicker for some rows and NumericUpDown for others based on a row cell value). The variables rowCellLocation, rowCellSize and rowId are set in a loop for each row.

My DataGridView selection mode is a full row selection.
I want to make the added control (DateTimePicker, NumericUpDown...) get focus when I switch to the row, for example, when I click on a row with the mouse.

To do so, I've tried the following:
In the loop that creates the controls, I set the control to the relevant row Tag property.
In the grid Row_Enter event (I also tried CurrentCellChanged) I added the following code:

```
if (gridParameters.CurrentRow.Tag != null)
{
    ((Control)gridParameters.CurrentRow.Tag).Focus();
}
```

I've also tried using Select() and also

```
this.ActiveControl = (Control)gridParameters.CurrentRow.Tag;
```

None of the above sets focus to the control.

I place a break point, and the code is getting to this line, the Tag property contain the control that need to be focused, and execute it, but I can't get the control to focus.

**UPDATE**: Setting focus to another control **outside** of the DataGridView, **works just fine** (for example, setting focus to an "OK" button works).

Comment: Try double clicking on the cell and see if control getting focused.

Comment: @Rahul Double clicking doesn't work. I'm not trying to edit a cell, I'm trying to set focus to another control when a specific row gets focus.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thank's, but as I've stated in the question, already tried ActiveControl property (actually got the idea from the question you linked which I've google before submitting my own question), which is not working as well. The grid control "keeps" the focus to the selected row.

Comment: Hmm, read down to the unformatted code, decided to format it and forgot to read it after. Things happen, sorry. But if this approach fails to work, why don't you try to create [custom columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)? As far as I understand that is the standard way to handle such tasks.

Comment: @EugenePodskal That's ok :) I've considered custom columns, but they will not help in this case, because I need different controls for different rows on the same column. For example, on the left column, for row 1 there will be a DateTimePicker, on row 2 NumericUpDown, on row 3 a DateTimePicker with only Time format etc.

Comment: You can try to make cell(and column) that [paints itself differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118251/how-to-paint-custom-control-on-datagridviewcell) depending on its custom property (like `enum {Date, Num}`), then just set this property to required value for each cell. Cell will paint itself with some image? that looks like required control (perhaps there is simpler and better way?). And on cell click you will add real control like in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/embedding-calendar-datetimepicker-control-into-datagridvie586/ depending on the value.

Comment: Well,  it is a bad idea from many points of view, but it can work, probably.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thank you for your efforts. I eventually gave up for now, unless someone will figure this out, could'nt find way the controls in the DGV controls collection are not focusing, and any "by-pass" seems to be not better than the current state.

Comment: No thanks needed. The solution I proposed seems to be worse than the problem itself. Nonetheless good luck. And if you won't be able to solve this problem in WinForms alone, you may consider [hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901253/hosting-wpf-controls-in-winforms) WPF dataGrid with [template selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506839/celltemplateselector-wont-choose-template-automatically). That one can be slow, but it at least [should work](http://wpfbugs.blogspot.ru/2014/01/how-to-programmatically-select-and.html).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem as it works fine for me. How many rows do you have in your DataGridView ? Can't you use TableLayoutPanel instead of DataGridView ?